# using multiple databases with django 1.6 gives "can't do subqueries" error

Tags: python, mysql, django

Today I tried to set up my django site to use multiple DBs that are in a writer/reader setup. After switching over, anywhere my code uses one QuerySet as a filter on another, I will sometimes get the dreaded "Can't do subqueries" error message.

I am using Django 1.6 and Django Cacheops 2.4.3. It looks like the issue should have been fixed in Django Chacheops 2.4.1.

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASS,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
        }
    },
    'replica1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': REPLICA_USER,
        'PASSWORD': REPLICA_PASS,
        'HOST': REPLICA_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app_name.replica_router.ReplicaRouter']
```

app_name/replica_router.py:

```
import random


class ReplicaRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """Reads go to a randomly chosen DB."""
        return random.choice(['default', 'replica1'])

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """All writes go to default."""
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Relations are allowed if both objects are in def/rep pool."""
        db_list = ('default', 'replica1')
        return obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return True
```

example of offending code in the view:

```
tokens = page_user.token_set.values_list('game_id', flat=True)
token_games = Game.objects.filter(id__in=tokens)
```

calling `token_games.count()` gives a stacktrace similar to the following:

```
Internal Server Error: /user/999/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my_name/code/my_app/my_app/core/views.py", line 1879, in user_and_game
    return display_user_page(request, uid, gid)
  File "/Users/my_name/code/my_app/my_app/core/views.py", line 1719, in display_user_page
    num_extra_badges = token_games.count() - 9
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 283, in count
    return cached_as(self)(lambda: self._no_monkey.count(self))()
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 78, in cached_as
    key_extra = [qs._cache_key() for qs in querysets]
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 137, in _cache_key
    sql, params = self.query.get_compiler(self._db or DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 94, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.query.where.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 106, in as_sql
    sql, params = self.make_atom(child, qn, connection)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 181, in make_atom
    lvalue, params = lvalue.process(lookup_type, params_or_value, connection)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 365, in process
    connection=connection, prepared=True)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 399, in get_db_prep_lookup
    sql, params = value._as_sql(connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1051, in _as_sql
    raise ValueError("Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.")
ValueError: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.
[24/Nov/2015 16:03:44] "GET /user/999/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 144360
```

Does anyone have any pointers? So far the best thing I can find to do is convert any values_list or query set into a list before filtering, but that seems quite inefficient and would require a massive refactor of my code.

Answer (score 0):

[This bug](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/issues/184) was fixed in cacheops 3.0. The fix should work with any router.